# How do I put a devoicing ring on top of [ŋ] using TIPA?

Tags: tipa

I am working with a language that has voiceless nasals, and I would like to be able to put the ring on top of the [ŋ] glyph.

So far, I have only been able to use `\textipa{\textsubring{N}}`, which puts the ring below the glyph. The math mode command `\mathring` does not seem to play well with the `\textipa` environment. Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version that goes above the letter is called simply "ring", and has the shortcut `\r`: `\r{N}`. This works both inside and outside the textipa environment.